# Move Code PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I am currently re-structuring my Python Code using PyCharm. I am often in the situation that I have to "move" many lines of code due to the indentation mechanism of Python. Moving lines of code "forward" is easy, as I just mark the lines and press "Tab", but I don't know how to do it "backwards"?

To make it clear consider a simple example for the structure problem:

```
for in_file in os.listdir(os.curdir):

    input_file = open(in_file, 'r')
    in_data = input_file.read().split("\n")

    print "Processing Data ..."

    in_array = []

    for line in in_data:

           converted_ts = to_timestamp(line)
           in_array.append(converted_ts)
```

When I remove the first line I have to move all other lines backwards. I guess there is a simple trick to do this and I hope that someone can actually help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How do I unindent lines?

> Unindent Selection <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> Move the selected block to the
>   previous indentation level.

Source [Basic Editing](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/basic-editing.html)